# Is my 3-circle Venn diagram for this set correct?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

[image: venn diagram]
(Apologies for the poor quality)

Comment: [wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=not%28A+xor+C%29+and+%28A+or+B%29) could have answered this just as easily as anyone here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is correct. Your steps are the correct ones.